# Sqlite3 in Python not fetching data

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite

I have a sqlite3 DB with a few rows in it. When I try to fetch data from it in Python, fetchall returns an empty list.

```
  con = sqlite3.connect("commands.db")
  cursor = con.cursor()
  con.execute("SELECT * FROM commands;")
  existing = cursor.fetchall()
  print(existing)
  # Prints []
```

The data is being inserted in a different part of the project fine. I verified this by opening the DB in "DB Browser for SQLite" and running the following command. This returned the data in the table with no problem.

```
SELECT * FROM commands;
```

Has anyone come across a similar issue?
Thank you for the help in advance!

Comment: `cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM commands;")` with `cursor` not `con`.

Comment: No need for the semicolon after the SELECT command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change `con.execute` to `cursor.execute`. Then it should work

Comment: Thank you! I spent about an hour trying to figure it out. I think I need stronger coffee ☕